# I get an error when compiling with an imported image resource

Tags: c#, picturebox, embedded-resource, about-box

This is turning into a nightmare!

I have a C# DLL project and it has the regular About Form. I go to add my own image:

[image]

I can see it listed and I accept:

[image]

It looks fine:

[image]

The moment I compile I get this error:

[image]

I have googled the error:

> The argument docData must implement the interface IVsTextStream

And it suggests deleting the RES file.

I am confused. I thought this would be a simple exercise and despite several attempts and can't use my own image.

Comment: Restart visual studio and try again

Comment: @SunilDhappadhule I have tried that several times now I am afraid. No joy. I even tried opened the about form RESX file, added the image, then setting it as embedded. But again at compile time it throws the same popup message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I do not know **why** the problem was happening. But here is my workaround:

1. I created a new C# DLL project.
2. I added the About Form.
3. I opened the form RESX file in the IDE.
4. I added the new image.
5. I set the image as embedded.
6. I deleted the existing image.
7. I renamed the new image the same as the old.
8. I restarted the project and the image showed fine.
9. I opened the RESX file with NotePad++ and copied the image bit over to my actual project about window RESX file.
10. It displays and compiles.